# Convert UML To Java

Tags: java, uml

i searched several forums and google in turn but couldn't find a proper way to do this. any help would be welcome.

Comment: no need. a friend just sent me this link. http://gforge.enseeiht.fr/projects/uml2java/

Comment: SO being a FAQ site, you can answer (and accept) your own question

Comment: eh.. what @mhaller told you was that you should post an answer to your own question and accept it, for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 1):

The UML conversion to java is really very poor. Except Omondo using either diagram<>model<>code live synchronization or diagram<>model live synchronization and then merge of UML and Java Ids in order to deliver quality code all the other tools are just crap !! I mean that:

- Why to generate code using just one package ?
- why to mix class and interfaces in the same package. This is so stupid for a java architect to mix class and its related interface so why for code generation purposes UML consider that both should be in the same package ? why the inheritance is not created if not working in the same package ? How dare can you say that UML is object modeling if you mix what should not be mixed just in order to have a dirty code generation ?

This Model Driven development is so mediocre that I have stopped using them and only live code and model synchronization provide an acceptable solution. I model and get my code, if my code is not what I consider good then I change my code and my diagram is updated. I can add java annotation in my code and my diagrams therefore my model could be immediately deployed and tested, no more painful stupid test etc...

UML could be fantastic but Model driven development has been full of  incredible lies !! Non productive modelers who never done any manual line of java code are trying to create architectures and code and give it to us (e.g. developer) in order to complete the job. The printed documentation is unsuable etc...

No code generation please because if you use Omondo EclipseUML then you will understand how the code should be generated.  This is UML with live code and model synchronization. I got my model and then totally refactor my code manually without losing my model and diagrams. Marvelous technology if used with Hibernate because my diagrams could be deployed live and tested using java annotations. Whaoo